# "Authorization Required" screen when attempting to submit a Case via an VF Site Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites

I have an externally available site configured.

We use it as our web-to-case solution.

When using the copy on our production instance it works fine, but when attempting to have someone outside the system put in a ticket via the sandbox instance it ends up not working correctly, providing the Authorization Required force.com page instead.

Is this a glitch with my code, or a feature of the sandbox instance?

Answer (score 1):

You should add the Visualforce page in your site's Public Access Setting.

Comment: It is in the site's public access setting. It's configured the same way on both production and sandbox instances and only provides the force.com message on sandbox.